# How to keep the width in cloned table same as original using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, clone

What I am trying to do is to copy the header of a table to new table.
So, I tried like below:

```
var srcTable = document.getElementById("bnn_GridView");
var clonedTable = srcTable.cloneNode(true);
clonedTable.id = "copiedTable";    // clear the id property of the cloned table

var container = document.getElementById("_bnn_GridView_tr");
container.appendChild(clonedTable);
```

Yes, I copied the original table

[image]

The above is copied table and the below is the original table.
It works find. But when I delete rows from the copied table, it goes like..

[image]

I lose all the width attributes. I know because I didn't copy the width from the original table. By the way, the original table, itself does not have the width property either.

This is the original table source.

```
<table id="bnn_GridView">
    <tr>
        <td><div>No</div></td>
        <td><div>Name</div></td>
        <td><div>User ID</div></td>
        <td><div>Address</div></td>
        <td><div>Telephone Number</div></td>
        <td><div>Zipcode</div></td>
        <td><div>Web Site</div></td>
        <td><div>Sex</div></td>
        <td><div>Birthday</div></td>
        <td><div>Note</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>Richard0</td>
        <td>richard</td>
        <td>5th texas street</td>
        <td>+82 114</td>
        <td>135-080</td>
        <td>http://www.website.com</td>
        <td>Male</td>
        <td>May 5 1980</td>
        <td>Good</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any ideas? to keep the width from the original table, even when I delete all the rows in copied table.

Comment: do you have the width of the original table set in css? if not, it just shrinks because of the difference of the content in.

Comment: unfortunatelly I don't have the width in css. That's my problem. I cannot predict the contents width. Any solutions?

Comment: yeah, set it to 100% and you should be golden

Comment: just a note: it is probably not a good idea to have 2 elements with same id on the page

Answer (score 0):

You will need to loop through each cell on a row in the source table and then explicitly set its width on the corresponding cell in the cloned table.

Comment: the original table's columns width return "".

Comment: Of course, because that's trying to read the actual value of the HTML attribute, which is not present. Use `.offsetWidth` instead.